# Unable to add apps in certain places

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

Last week I added the RDZ RSSreader app which has been added to one of my pages and working fine. Today I have had problems adding apps - this one to another page within the same site collection, and another which has not been used across the site at all. Both have given me odd error messages:

> "The app package does not support the culture en-GB specified for
>   installation."  Correlation ID: 522f329c-66d8-c00d-29c4-2978fd3e4227

I guess this is around installation settings. Today is the first day I've seen some changes where I can add apps in certain parts of my site but not others. Is this common, and can it be circumvented? I can't even uninstall this RSS reader now.

Anyone else with similar issues? Hardly worth integrating an app which solves a problem in one instance.... Nor one which only works in a particular country.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I'm on SharePoint 365.....

Answer (score 1):

Problem sussed and solved - it is to do with the installation of the language pack. You must ensure that the when you want to install, that the language options match the specified supported language within the SharePoint store - So with my regional settings defaulted as English (UK), I have to check that the app installs as English (USA) as its supported language.

If you forget, only way to solve is remove the app (as it stays perpetually trying and failing to install) and then re-install it.